# Stata calculate % change between years

Tags: stata

I have the following columns in my data

Firm - revenue - industry - year

I want to calculate the percentage change in total revenue for each industry between 2008 and 2015.

I tried:

```
by industry: egen tot_2008 = sum(revenue) if year == 2008
by industry: egen tot_2015 = sum(revenue) if year == 2015
gen change = (tot_2015-tot_2008)/tot_2008
```

But this doesn't work as the `if`s restrict which years the `egen` creates values for as well as which years are included in each sum.

Comment: I have corrected multiple typos that would cause the code as you showed it to fail. Note that (1) column is a not a Stata term (use variable instead) (2) your code gives proportional change, not percent change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you realise, the problem with your code is that 2008 and 2015 values will be non-missing values only for those years respectively, and hence never not missing on both variables. Here is one way to spread values to all years for each industry:

```
by industry: egen tot_2008 = total(revenue / (year == 2008)) 
by industry: egen tot_2015 = total(revenue / (year == 2015)) 
gen change = (tot_2015-tot_2008)/tot_2008
```

That hinges on expressions such as `year == 2008` being evaluated as 1 if true and 0 if false. If you divide by 0, the result is a missing value, which Stata ignores, which is exactly what you want. Taking totals over all observations in an industry ensures that the same value is recorded for each industry.

Here is another way that some find more explicit:

```
by industry: egen tot_2008 = total(cond(year == 2008, revenue, .)) 
by industry: egen tot_2015 = total(cond(year == 2015, revenue, .)) 
gen change = (tot_2015-tot_2008)/tot_2008
```

which hinges on the same principle, that missings will be ignored.

Note the use of the `egen` function `total()` here. The `egen` function `sum()` still works, and is the same function, but that name is undocumented as of Stata 9, in an attempt to avoid confusion with the Stata function `sum()`.

To avoid double (indeed multiple) counting, use

```
 egen tag = tag(industry)
```

to tag just one observation for each industry, to be used in graphs and tables for which you want that.

For discussion, see [here](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0055), sections 9 and 10.